# Should we style a fieldset tag as hidden for accessibility concerns?

Tags: html, accessibility, user-experience

From what I've read in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741328/why-do-we-need-a-fieldset-tag), the main purposes of the fieldset tag is not logically group other labels and inputs semantically and to style them.

If I don't want to styling option, but want the semantic meaning, should I just hide it? or not use it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your design is still visually correct (i.e. focus is indicated correctly, layout makes sense, logical tab order etc.) then you can use a `fieldset` and hide it visually (you can't use a visually hidden class on the `fieldset` itself as that would hide everything).

In order to use it correctly you do need to add a `legend` explaining what the `fieldset` is about.

A `fieldset` and `legend` can enhance usability for a screen reader user (and helps google understand your form so a tiny bonus for SEO) so you should definitely include it in your form if it is appropriate semantically.

In order to remove styling you remove the border on the `fieldset` and then add a `visually-hidden` css class to the legend.

I have put together a quick snippet to show you how I would set it up without any visual styling.

The group would be read: "filter our work by" & option selected by a screen reader.

```css
fieldset{
  border: none;
}
.visually-hidden { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line */
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend class="visually-hidden">filter our work by</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" id="webdesign">
    <label for="webdesign">web design</label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" id="graphicdesign">
    <label for="graphicdesign">graphic design</label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" id="signage">
    <label for="signage">Signage Production</label>
</fieldset>
```