# What special tag can I use in CSS to create a form box that has text in its border?

Tags: css

What I would like to do is this:
[image]

P.S: The red arrow is my own adding. Note that the actual grey line surrounding the form box is in fact not a border, as it was pointed out to me by my instructor. I would like to know how to add text to the line surrounding the form box in CSS.

Comment: If it's not a border then the element is probably a [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need a fieldset tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741328/why-do-we-need-a-fieldset-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `fieldset` tag followed by a `legend` tag.
From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your favorite monster</legend>

    <input type="radio" id="kraken" name="monster">
    <label for="kraken">Kraken</label><br/>

    <input type="radio" id="sasquatch" name="monster">
    <label for="sasquatch">Sasquatch</label><br/>

    <input type="radio" id="mothman" name="monster">
    <label for="mothman">Mothman</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```